# RabbitMQ: Callback Functions For When Something is Popped off Queue

Tags: rabbitmq

Not sure how to do this, or even if it can be done.  I need to write a function that listens to a queue and fires when something is popped from it.

So basically:
Push object to  queue
Consumer pops object from queue
** some function then says, "'object' has been popped from queue"

Is this something that can be done w/ Rabbit?

Comment: Where is this function supposedly going to be fired? In the producer or in the consumer's process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing my plans, I realized I came up w/ the wrong approach.  I'm having my consumer post back a message to my program saying this particular message has been read.  This follows more of the queue concept.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to presume that you mean that you want to inform the producer that the consumer has consumed a message from the queue.  I will add that I think you may have misunderstood the MQ concept here and either you need to use a RPC method, which can be done with RabbitMQ, or you need to redesign your system .  However what you require is possible.

I would use in a loop in a thread in the producer:

```
`GetResponse gr = channel.basicGet(queueName, false);`
```

use false so that the the next message is not popped off the queue.
then

```
`int msgCount = gr.getMessageCount();`
```

will give you the number of messages on the queue.
Sleep afterwards for a short amount of time then check again.  This will be very difficult if the producer is sending a large amount of messages to the queue.  But if you increment a total of messages sent to the queue and remove the messages you know have been consumed this will give you and idea if the messages have been consumed or not.

I am not 100% that this will be problem free, and I will reiterate that I think something is wrong with your design by attempting this.